# Why i am getting error in jquery.mobile-1.4.2.js?

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am using jquery mobile 1.4.2.
This is working fine in all the pages except one URL.
When i click on that link it is displaying with empty content.
In console its showing error like

### Error

"Type Error: $.widget.extend is not a function

options );"

at code.j query.com/mobile/1.4.2/j query.mobile-1.4.2.js.
I tried By removing

```
data-role="page" then its displaying the content
```

Please any one help me i am not getting what is the problem?

Comment: This is not enough information, we need much more if you want us to solve your problem. Are you using multi page or multi HTML template? Can you add HTML of your problematic page?

Comment: I am using multi HTML templates its working in all templates except one template

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to change data-role="none" for a particuler url?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23776331/how-to-change-data-role-none-for-a-particuler-url)

Comment: @user3350169 Please close your other questions asking about the same issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23776331/how-to-change-data-role-none-for-a-particuler-url

Comment: @user3350169 By removing the data-role you are essentially not loading JQuery Mobile on the page, hence you don't get the JQuery mobile error.